# What is the password to Puppet's Web Console for the Puppet Learning VM

Tags: puppet

I've got Puppet's learning VM up and running. I can run puppet from the console and I've got root privileges on the VM. I can do the labs with the puppet console. When I connect to the web console to perform activities in the Puppet learning labs and enter in the documented username password of "puppet@example.com" and "learningpuppet" (no quotes) I get a bad username or password response.

Trying to run the "[reset password](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/trouble_console-db.html#recovering-from-a-lost-console-admin-password)" ruby script reports other errors (the schema https doesn't accept registry part).

Comment: *what is the password of your online banking?*

Comment: I'll tell you mine if you tell me yours.

Answer (score 3):

The documents are out of date. The username/password is admin/puppetlabs. The enterprise console's username/password is mentioned in the login message (which you won't see because you're a good admin using SSH instead of telnet) located in the following file: /etc/motd.